# Python - Finance Matplotlib related

Tags: matplotlib, finance

I'm new to python and I'm testing the finance matploblib module.

I need to get the price and date values when the ma20 = ma50

Give me a clue on how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
# Modules
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.finance as finance
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

# Define quote
startdate = datetime.date(2005,1,1)
today = enddate = datetime.date.today()
ticker = 'nvda'

# Catch CSV
fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, startdate, enddate)

# From CSV to REACARRAY
r = mlab.csv2rec(fh); fh.close()
# Order by Desc
r.sort()


### Methods Begin
def moving_average(x, n, type='simple'):
    """
    compute an n period moving average.

    type is 'simple' | 'exponential'

    """
    x = np.asarray(x)
    if type=='simple':
        weights = np.ones(n)
    else:
        weights = np.exp(np.linspace(-1., 0., n))

    weights /= weights.sum()


    a =  np.convolve(x, weights, mode='full')[:len(x)]
    a[:n] = a[n]
    return a
### Methods End


prices = r.adj_close
dates = r.date
ma20 = moving_average(prices, 20, type='simple')
ma50 = moving_average(prices, 50, type='simple')


plot.plot(prices)
plot.plot(ma20)
plot.plot(ma50)
plot.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using numpy, you can use numpy's boolean indexing for arrays:

```
equal = ma20==ma50
print(dates[equal])
print(prices[equal])
```

'equal' is a boolean array of the same length as dates and prices. Numpy then picks from dates and prices only those entries where equal==True, or, equivalently, ma20==ma50.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works, but only catches one occurrence, it is possible to catch all the occurrences? Best Regards,

Comment: The problem was the decimals, equal = np.round(ma20,2)==np.round(ma50,2)

Comment: @Andre: you might want to have a look at the Decimal package then, http://pydoc.org/2.4.1/decimal.html